# PHP authentication: HTTP vs SESSION - which one is more secure?

Tags: php, session, authentication, slim, php-5.6

I have baffled by the authentication using HTTP headers as I have seen many APIs or web apps using HTTP to authenticate login user. I have been using PHP SESSION though.

And I just want to know which is more secure.

For instance,

Using SESSION with Slim:

```
session_cache_limiter(false);
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// @ref: http://help.slimframework.com/discussions/questions/265-return-custom-error-code-and-error-message
$authAdmin = function () {

    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    // Check for authenticated user in the session
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
        $app->redirect('login');
    }
};

// Config.
$app->config(array(
    'templates.path' => 'template/',
));

// Home.
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Hello World ";
});

// Access admin area.
$app->get('/admin', $authAdmin, function () use ($app) {
   echo "Hello Admin ";
})->name('admin');

// Get and post the login form.
$app->map('/login', function () use ($app) {

    // Test for Post & make a cheap security check, to get avoid from bots
    if ($app->request()->isPost() && sizeof($app->request()->post()) >= 2) {

        // Don't forget to set the correct attributes in your form (name="username" + name="password")
        $post = (object)$app->request()->post();

        // Validate the username and password against the row in the db.
        if(isset($post->username) && isset ($post->password) && ($post->username === 'demo' && $post->password === 'demo')) {
            $_SESSION['user'] = 'xxxx';
            $app->redirect('admin');
        } else {
            $app->redirect('login');
        }
    }

    // render login
    $app->render('login.twig');

})->via('GET','POST')->name('login');

$app->run();
```

Using HTTP with Slim:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

// To test:
// 1. use jquery ajax to set and send the http headers.
// 2. use Chrome postman to set and send the http headers.
// 3. use cURL to set and send the http headers.
// @ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGGtLoEpqm4
$authAdmin = function() {

    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    $request = $app->request;
    $httpUser = $request->headers->get('x-user');
    $httpPass = $request->headers->get('x-pass');

    // Validate the user and password against the row in the db.
    $isValid = ($httpUser === 'demo' && $httpPass === 'demo') ? true : false;
    try {
        if ($isValid === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid user and password");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $app->status(401);
        echo json_encode(array(
            'status' => 401,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ));
        $app->stop();
    }
};

// Config.
$app->config(array(
    'templates.path' => 'template/',
));

// Home.
$app->get('/', function () {
    echo "Hello World ";
});

// Admin.
$app->get('/admin', $authAdmin, function () use ($app) {
   echo "Hello Admin ";
})->name('admin');

// Get login form.
$app->get('/login', function () use ($app) {
    $app->render('login.twig');
});

// Post login form.
$app->post('/login', function () use ($app) {

    // Test for Post & make a cheap security check, to get avoid from bots
    if ($app->request()->isPost() && sizeof($app->request()->post()) >= 2) {

        // Don't forget to set the correct attributes in your form (name="username" + name="password")
        $post = (object)$app->request()->post();

        // Validate the username and password against the row in the db.
        if(isset($post->username) && isset ($post->password) && ($post->username === 'demo' && $post->password === 'demo')) {

            // Return the result for jQuery to set the http headers.
            echo json_encode(array(
                'x-user' => $post->username,
                'x-pass' => $post->password
            ));
        } else {
            $app->redirect('login');
        }
    }
});

$app->run();
```

Any ideas and thoughts?

Comment: HTTP Authorization Headers are more secured any day.

Comment: `HTTP Authorization Headers are more secured any day` why?

Comment: HTTP authorization headers must be sent with every request. When using sessions, the client authenticates once. IMO it's better not have to handle and secure the session data. Also, using HTTP authentication, you may provide a stateless service/application. But this last doesn't have much with security.

Comment: what is a stateless service/application?

Comment: `But this last doesn't have much with security.` - i don't understand this. why it `doesn't have much with security`?